# Installing libraries when running multiple versions of Python

Tags: python, pydev

This may have been asked before but I wasn't able to find any information on it. If I am running multiple versions of Python, namely `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.3.5`, how do I install libraries for a particular version among the two?

Answer (score 3):

You would rather consider using [Virtual Environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for Python. It will let you create separate and independent Python environments, for different version of Python, as well as packages.

I would also recommend [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper), which just wraps `virutalenv` and adds handy functionality.

So concretely for your situation, you may create two environments for Python `2.7` and `3.3.5`, and install the required libraries for each `virtualenv`. Here is a brief example of what you will have to do:

```
$ mkvirtualenv venv27  # This will create and activate virtualenv for Python 2.7
$ deactivate  # ...to deactivate venv27
$ mkvirtualenv venv33 -p /usr/bin/python3.3  # same for Python 3.3.5
$ deactivate
```

Note the `-p` option, which specifies the Python interpreter for that virtual environment.

After creating your virtual environment, you can start working on them using the `workon` utility:

```
$ workon venv27  # or venv33
```

Comment: Thank You. For some reason when I do `$ mkvirtualenv venv27` in the command prompt I get the message `'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

Comment: I have aded the `$` sign as just an formatting indication, that it should be ran in the terminal. So you should actually run `mkvirtualenv venv27`.

Comment: I suppose you are using Windows, so maybe [this](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/) will also help you.